# Java Bouncy Castle Cryptography - Encrypt with AES

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

How do I implement AES encryption with the java bouncy castle library?  Example code or a link to example code would be nice :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you download the [bcprov source](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk16-145.zip), you'll see the class `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.test.AESTest`. It shows you how to set up the bouncyCastle provider, create encryption and decryption `Cipher` objects, set up `CipherOutputStream`s and call the write methods on those streams.

**Edit**: 
seems like link is broken. Look [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/AESTest.java) for AESTest

Comment: For convenience, [`AESTest`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/AESTest.java) can now also be found on GitHub.

Comment: They are hard-coding IVs in that test, which is something you shouldn't do. IV must be unique for any given ciphertext (a nonce).

Comment: Just a note. link is broken.

Answer (score -2):

Check the `org.bouncycastle.crypto.test` package.