# Java AES-256 Decryption - translating code from ActionScript 3

Tags: java, actionscript-3, encryption, aes, rijndael

I have a working decryption in ActionScript 3, now I want to get the same result when decrypting in Java. (I know that the OFB-mode and NullPadding is probably not preferred, but that's what I used back then and that is what I need to decrypt now...)

(very old) Adobe ActionScript 3 code:

```
static public function decryptTest(): Boolean {
    var iv: String = "0df1eff724d50157ab048d9ff214b73c";
    var cryptext: String = "2743be20314cdc768065b794904a0724e64e339ea6b4f13c510e2d2e8c95dd7409aa0aefd20daae80956dd2978c98d6e914d1d7b5b5be47b491d91e7e4f16f7f30d991ba80a81bafd8f0d7d83755ba0ca66d6b208424529c7111bc9cd6d11786f3f604a0715f";
    var kkey: String = "375f22c03371803ca6d36ec42ae1f97541961f7359cf5611bbed399b42c7c0be";

    var kdata: ByteArray = Hex.toArray(kkey);
    var data: ByteArray = Hex.toArray(cryptext);
    var name: String = 'aes-256-ofb';
    var pad:IPad = new NullPad();
    var mode: ICipher = Crypto.getCipher(name, kdata, pad);
    pad.setBlockSize(mode.getBlockSize());
    trace("mode block size: " + mode.getBlockSize());

    if (mode is IVMode) {
        var ivmode:IVMode = mode as IVMode;
        ivmode.IV = Hex.toArray(iv);
    }
    mode.decrypt(data);

    var res: String = data.toString();
    trace("result: " + res);

    return res == "01020506080b10131c22292d313536393b464c535466696d6e7d7f808a8e9899a2adb1b8babcbebfc1c6c7c8cecfd8e0e4e8ef";
}

trace("decryption test: " + netplay.decryptTest());
```

Flash output is:

```
mode block size: 16
result: 01020506080b10131c22292d313536393b464c535466696d6e7d7f808a8e9899a2adb1b8babcbebfc1c6c7c8cecfd8e0e4e8ef
decryption test: true
```

**What have I tried?**

I have tried two different approaches in Java, one using the built-in `Cipher` class, and one using [this code/class](http://www.devkb.org/java/50-AES-256-bits-encrypter-decrypter-Java-source-code). However, the first approach gives me an IllegalKeyException and the other is giving me garbage. Also, the second approach doesn't clearly specify how to enter the IV-data for the decryption, nor does it let me specify the OFB-mode or the padding.

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1023)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:789)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:848)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1347)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1281)
    at test.net.zomis.ZomisTest.decryptCipher(ZomisTest.java:112)
@Test
public void decryptCipher() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    String iv = "0df1eff724d50157ab048d9ff214b73c";
    String cryptext = "2743be20314cdc768065b794904a0724e64e339ea6b4f13c510e2d2e8c95dd7409aa0aefd20daae80956dd2978c98d6e914d1d7b5b5be47b491d91e7e4f16f7f30d991ba80a81bafd8f0d7d83755ba0ca66d6b208424529c7111bc9cd6d11786f3f604a0715f";
    String key = "375f22c03371803ca6d36ec42ae1f97541961f7359cf5611bbed399b42c7c0be"; // Hexadecimal String, will be converted to non-hexadecimal String
    String expectedResult = "01020506080b10131c22292d313536393b464c535466696d6e7d7f808a8e9899a2adb1b8babcbebfc1c6c7c8cecfd8e0e4e8ef";

    byte[] kdata = Util.hex2byte(key);

    Assert.assertEquals(32, kdata.length); // 32 bytes = 256-bit key

    String result;

    Cipher cipher;
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/OFB/NoPadding");
    // Below line is 112, which is causing exception
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(kdata, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    byte[] cryptData = Util.hex2byte(cryptext);
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(cryptData);
    result = new String(ciphertext);


    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
}

@Test
public void decryptAES() {
    String iv = "0df1eff724d50157ab048d9ff214b73c"; 
    // Problem: Where should I specify the IV ???? Currently it is an unused variable...

    String cryptext = "2743be20314cdc768065b794904a0724e64e339ea6b4f13c510e2d2e8c95dd7409aa0aefd20daae80956dd2978c98d6e914d1d7b5b5be47b491d91e7e4f16f7f30d991ba80a81bafd8f0d7d83755ba0ca66d6b208424529c7111bc9cd6d11786f3f604a0715f";
    String key = "375f22c03371803ca6d36ec42ae1f97541961f7359cf5611bbed399b42c7c0be"; // Hexadecimal String, will be converted to non-hexadecimal String
    String expectedResult = "01020506080b10131c22292d313536393b464c535466696d6e7d7f808a8e9899a2adb1b8babcbebfc1c6c7c8cecfd8e0e4e8ef";

    Assert.assertEquals(64, key.length());

    AES aes = new AES();
    aes.setKey(Util.hex2byte(key));
    byte[] byteCryptedData = Util.hex2byte(cryptext);
    String byteCryptedString = new String(byteCryptedData);

    while (byteCryptedString.length() % 16 != 0) byteCryptedString += " ";


    String result = aes.Decrypt(byteCryptedString);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, result); // Assertion Failed
}
```

**The question:**
How can I make Java decrypt in the same way that ActionScript 3 does? Of course, I'd like to get the same result on both.

Comment: a small error `new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"))` should be `new IvParameterSpec(Util.hex2byte(iv));` but `Illegal key size` stil her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is giving you an `Illegal key size` error message because you don't have the unrestricted policy files installed. Java will refuse to work with "strong" key lengths (e.g. 256-bit AES) without these in place.

If it is legal to do so in your jurisdiction, Google for "*Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files*" and download the version applicable to your Java installation. You will end up with two files to dump into `lib/security` in your JRE.

Comment: What if I want to deploy my JAR-file to others, can I deploy my JAR together with the policy files somehow, or does all computers that want to run my JAR-file also need to download and install the policy files?

Comment: Really, each person should do this themselves. It is not necessarily legal in all countries for this strength of cryptography to be used. I would recommend you catch the exception and present a pleasant message to the user (even including download links).

Comment: Just check with "Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy" and first test passed.

Comment: Yes, this work. I will change both the AS3 and Java encryption in the future to make it easier. Perhaps 256-bit AES encryption is a little overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are such libraries, have a look at http://www.bouncycastle.org/ . This is a bit more specific [Java Bouncy Castle Cryptography - Encrypt with AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435338/java-bouncy-castle-cryptography-encrypt-with-aes)