# AES encrypt/decrypt with Bouncy Castle provider

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

Here is my implementation of a AES 256 encrypt and decrypt, developed with the native library of JDK 5:

```
public static String encrypt(String key, String toEncrypt) throws Exception {
    Key skeySpec = generateKeySpec(key);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
    byte[] encryptedValue = Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted);
    return new String(encryptedValue);
}

public static String decrypt(String key, String encrypted) throws Exception {
    Key skeySpec = generateKeySpec(key);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted.getBytes());
    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(decodedBytes);
    return new String(original);
}
```

I want to implement the same methods with the Boucy Castle API (Java): I've searched a lot, tested a lot, without results ... can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You do realize that you will be using the same API, but just a different provider right? Anyways, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435338/java-bouncy-castle-cryptography-encrypt-with-aes).

Comment: Note that AES256 is by default disabled in all Java versions from Oracle. You have to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for Java 5. BTW: Java 5 is outdated and insecure. Don't use it anymore.

Comment: I know that Robert, thanks.
Perception, i want to use Boucny Castle because it's more portable thant the native lib of Java (only from JDK 6+)

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate but [the original](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2435338) has dreadfully sparse answers.

Comment: Sure, it is duplicate but the scenario is different.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You would either use

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES", "BC");
```

or else

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES", new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

That said, `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` uses [Electronic Codebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation), which is insecure.  You either want Cipher Block Chaining (`Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`) or Counter (`Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding")`) modes; they are both secure, the primary difference being that CBC requires padding while CTR does not.