# Keeping track of a hashed password's original length

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, sha1

I am saving SHA1 password in shared SharedPreferences if user had opted for "remeber me" option while singing into app..

so next time user is on login screen he will have user name and passwod feild already filled in by SharedPreferences resource....

Problem here is, since i am saving encrpted SHA1 password that is always 40 in length no matter how short or long actual password string is..so user will see 40 password dots  in password text box .. 
user might get confuse with this password length....

so how could i display that original string of password there...??
It would have been nice if i could simply decrpyt that string but that unfortunately is not an option i can rely on.

so is there any other way?????

Comment: `I am saving SHA1 encrpyted password` It's not encrypted, it's _hashed_. It means that it **can't be recovered**, so you won't be able to display the original password. Switch to an encryption algorithm if you want to be able to recover the password

Comment: You can rather try AES which is more friendly - in the context of your question.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge of this kind of encryption, or your app, but wouldn't it be possible to get the length of the typed in password, save that in another SharedPreference and then only display that amount of characters when loading it again? So it only displays 10 chars if the password is 10 chars, but it actually uses the "original" encrypted password.

Comment: Side note: it is not very safe to store passwords in the SharedPreferences. Alternatively, you can have a look at the `AccountManager`.

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435338/java-bouncy-castle-cryptography-encrypt-with-aes) about BouncyCastle AES encryption / decryption might help.